# how can i be sure that people cant view my code?

Tags: html

I would like to ask if it's possible for people to view code I can see in Microsoft debugger.

I'm probably just being paranoid, but can other people see my code using their debugger?

I can't see the password and login when I just enter view code, but I can in debugger. I'm pretty sure that I'm safe, but I cant afford to make a mistake.

Comment: Need more context. Post sample code with passwords `<removed>`

Comment: You've tagged this with HTML. If you're writing HTML your users definitely _can_ see your code, and they don't even need a debugger. There is no way to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I Advice you for limit your client side codes and depend more on server side, Special for the valued algorithms and new ideas.

**Php** is a good simple way but if you want more security,

better to mix server side codes with **ASP C#** or **java** to have the ability of encryption, encoding, secured textString and ... cts.

Answer (score 1):

**Obfuscation** could be another good option for you if you have client-side code you don't want easily viewed by others.

On the part where you can see login credentials:  I believe you'll want to look into storing passwords as **Salted Hashes**. There are many other ways to ensure passwords stay confidential.

These are certainly not plug and play solutions by any means and I'd highly recommend doing your own research on these topics before doing so.